# Java 8 best way to parse text date to millisecond timestamp

Tags: java, thread-safety

I want to create a Java class with thread-safe static methods to parse dates. I understand that some of the Java 7 (and earlier) date time classes are not thread-safe. What is the best thread-safe implementation in Java 8 of this functionality:

```
String text = "5/16/2008";
long timestamp = DateUtil.getTimestamp(text);
```

In Java 7 and earlier, you would do this:

```
public class DateUtil {

    public static long getTimestamp(String text) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        long timestamp = df.parse(text).getTime();
        return timestamp;
    }

}
```

But instead of creating a new instance of `DateFormat` for every call, I want to share a single static instance for all calls to this static `getTimestamp` method. My understanding is that this is not thread-safe.

One key requirement is that the text I want to parse has a short date like "5/16/2008" without HH:mm:ss resolution.

I also don't want to use a third party library like Joda-Time, but rather only standard Java 8 classes.

Comment: The third party Joda-Time library was (mostly) made into standard Java 8 classes in the `java.time.*` packages.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version of your code refactored to use the `java.time.*` package in Java 8.  It uses a `static final` formatter instance, which is thread-safe and immutable, unlike `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");

    public static long getTimestamp(String text) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
        return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()).getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joda-time` lib. `DateTime` is immutable - and once created the values do not change, so class can safely be passed around and used in multiple threads without synchronization.
A companion mutable class to DateTime is `MutableDateTime`, of which the class can be modified and are not thread-safe.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
    .withLocale(Locale.ROOT).withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC());
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(text);
```

Reference of `DateTimeFormatt`: [DatetimeFormat api](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in ck1's answer, usage of `java.time` API is a better approach than the legacy classes. `DateTimeFormatter` is immutable and thread-safe, and using a static final instance of it will solve your problem.
The only part where I differ from that answer is in the code , where the `Date` class is used to get the time. I would like to take the `java.time` approach here as well. Below is my version :

```
public class DateUtil {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");

    public static long getTimestamp(String text) {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
        return Instant.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())).toEpochMilli();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "5/16/2008";
        long timestamp = DateUtil.getTimestamp(text);
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```